# Problem in listings, hyphenation not correct

Tags: listings, hyphenation

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn,openany]{book}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{mytex}[LaTeX]{TeX}{
alsoletter={\\},
morekeywords=[3]{\\mbox,\mbox,},
literate={\{}{{\textcolor{blue}{\{}}}{1} {\}}{{\textcolor{blue}{\}}}}{1}
{ı}{\i}1 {ş}{\c{s}}1 {ğ}{\u{g}}1,
}

\lstset{language=mytex}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle1}{
basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily, 
keywordstyle=[3]{\color{green}},
identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
breaklines=true,
columns=fullflexible,
}

\lstset{style=mystyle1}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\chapter[Fillerin Anatomisi]{Fillerin değişik kıtalardaki anatomilerinin karşılaştırılması}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

and displaying

[image]

Correct hyphenation, de-ği-şik and kar-şı-laş-tı-rıl-ma-sı. Like below the picture.

[image]

How can I do?

Comment: Why would you want hyphenation in a source code listing? If I see a hyphen in source code, I assume it is part of the source code.

Comment: What about my answer here, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 7):

`listings` does not hyphenate words.

You have those line breaks simply because you've defined `ı` and `ş` to be printed "literate".

One thing you can do is to manually insert linebreaks by using `escapeinside={\%}{\%}` as an option and then inserting `%\linebreak%` in the points where you want to break.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn,openany]{book}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{mytex}[LaTeX]{TeX}{
alsoletter={\\},
morekeywords=[3]{\\mbox,\mbox,},
literate={\{}{{\textcolor{blue}{\{}}}{1} {\}}{{\textcolor{blue}{\}}}}{1}
{ı}{\i}1 {ş}{\c{s}}1 {ğ}{\u{g}}1,
}

\lstset{language=mytex}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle1}{
basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=[3]{\color{green}},
identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
breaklines=true,
columns=fullflexible,
escapeinside={\%}{\%}
}

\lstset{style=mystyle1}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\chapter[Fillerin Anatomisi]{Fillerin deği%\linebreak%şik kıtalardaki anatomilerinin karşılaş%\linebreak%tırılması}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Hope you don't really want to insert hyphenation signs in your listings, but in case you wanted, replace `%\linebreak%` with `%- \linebreak%`.

Answer (score 3):

Some comments other than karlkoeller's answer:

In `lstmisc.sty` there are

> ```
> \lst@AddToHook{Init}
>     {\lst@ifbreaklines
>          \hbadness\@M \pretolerance\@M
>          \@rightskip\@flushglue \rightskip\@rightskip % \raggedright
>          \leftskip\z@skip \parindent\z@
>          \def\lst@parshape{\parshape\tw@ \@totalleftmargin\linewidth
>                            \lst@breakshape}%
>      \else
>          \let\lst@discretionary\@empty
>      \fi}
> ```

You can see that `listings` set (pre)tolerance to be the maximum value. In general this means that TeX will never look for a better breaking point --- **It just  breaks** right after some character fills the current line.

But `listings` provides `breakatwhitespace` option to imitate the behavior of editors we use. Besides, keys `prebreak` and `postbreak` are used to insert the hyphen-character.

By the way, consider `moretexcs` instead of `morekeywords`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn,openany]{book}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color,keystroke,listings}


\def\blue#1{\textcolor{blue}{\tt#1}}

\lstdefinelanguage{mytex}[LaTeX]{TeX}{
    moretexcs=[3]{mbox,chapter},
    literate={\{}{\blue\{}1 {\}}{\blue{\}}}1 {ı}{\i}1 {ş}{\c s}1 {ğ}{\u g}1
}

\lstset{language=mytex}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle1}{
    basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily, 
    texcsstyle=*[3]{\color{green}},
    identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
    breaklines,
    prebreak=-,%\mbox{$\Enter$},
    columns=fullflexible,
}

\lstset{style=mystyle1}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\chapter[Fillerin Anatomisi]{Fillerin değişik kıtalardaki anatomilerinin karşılaştırılması}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[prebreak=\mbox{$\Enter$}]
\chapter[Fillerin Anatomisi]{Fillerin değişik kıtalardaki anatomilerinin karşılaştırılması}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the first case it works by chance. You are not sure that `listings` breaks the line at the hyphenation point.

Comment: @karlkoeller Yes. I once want to change the margins so that you would not think I won. I Just pointed out why hyphening is hard in `listings`. But we still got a chance because you can rewrite the process between `\lst@ifbreaklines` and `\fi`